# Dynamic column names in SQL Where Clause

Tags: sql, automation

I have a situation here that i am trying to automate. Please help. If there are any links/references to similar problem. Please share, i did some research but could not find exactly what i needed.
So I have a table with about 30 columns of which First column contains list of all Emp IDs and the rest 29 Columns contains Flags "Y","N". Column name is basically product name that the EMP is eligible for.

The data looks something like this.

```
Table name: EMPPRODMAP                  
EMPCODE PROD1   PROD2   PROD3   PROD4   PROD5
703 Y   N   N   Y   N
238 N   Y   N   Y   N
806 Y   Y   Y   N   Y
812 N   Y   Y   N   Y
671 Y   N   Y   N   N
```

Now, there are clusters of Business units. like below

```
TABLENAME: CLUSTERMAP
CLUSTER PRODS
CL1 PROD1
CL1 PROD2
CL2 PROD3
CL2 PROD4
CL3 PROD1
CL3 PROD4
CL3 PROD2
CL3 PROD5
```

So what i need to do is make a list of all the EMPs that are eligible for CL1 prods and so on. So my SQL Currently looks like

```
    Sel EMPCODE,'CL1' as Cluster,'PROD1' as PRODUCT from EMPPRODMAP where PROD1 = 'Y'
Union
Sel EMPCODE,'CL1' as Cluster,'PROD2' as PRODUCT from EMPPRODMAP where PROD2 = 'Y'
```

I am looking for a way where i can leverage the table CLUSTERMAP to automatee this process, because currently i have to write multiple queries for all clusters and maintainance is also a pain since the clustermap is dynamic for each quater and list changes.

I am looking for a no plain SQL workaround to this, no Procedure/functions due to system limitations.

Note: I have created fake data. Please let me know if something is not clear/understandable.

All help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Please follow step-by-step.

```
begin try

CREATE TABLE #Productnames --Holds list of all products, fetched from column names 
(
Prodname varchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #TempResultSet --Holds data of EMPPRODMAP in EMPOCODE-Product pair
(
EMPCODE int
,ProductName varchar(20)
)

--Fetch column names of table EMPPRODMAP except column EMPCODE and insert into the table #Productnames
INSERT INTO #Productnames
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'EMPPRODMAP'
and COLUMN_NAME <> 'EMPCODE'
ORDER BY ordinal_position 

DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(20),@EMP INT,@sqlSTMT NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Iterate on each EMPCODE
DECLARE empCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT EMPCODE FROM EMPPRODMAP

--Iterate on each product name
DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Prodname FROM #Productnames

OPEN empCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM empCursor
INTO @EMP
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  OPEN prodCursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor
  INTO @VAR

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
  --Inserting data in #TempResultSet in valid EMPCODE-Product pairs
    SET @sqlSTMT = N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPPRODMAP WHERE EMPCODE = @EMP AND '+@VAR+ ' = 1)
                INSERT INTO #TempResultSet
                SELECT @EMP ,@VAR'

    exec sp_executesql @sqlSTMT, N'@EMP INT,@VAR VARCHAR(20)', @EMP,@VAR

    FETCH NEXT FROM prodCursor
    INTO @VAR
  END
  CLOSE prodCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM empCursor
INTO  @EMP
END
CLOSE empCursor
DEALLOCATE empCursor
DEALLOCATE prodCursor

--Fetching your required result set
SELECT EPM.EMPCODE,CM.CLUSTER,EPM.ProductName
FROM
#TempResultSet EPM
INNER JOIN
CLUSTERMAP CM
ON EPM.ProductName = CM.PRODS
ORDER BY EPM.EMPCODE
DROP TABLE #Productnames;
DROP TABLE #TempResultSet;
end TRy
begin catch
DROP TABLE #Productnames;
DROP TABLE #TempResultSet;
throw;
end catch
```

So, major challenge in your tables is that there is no direct relationship between two tables. So,basically I changed the structure of your table EMPPRODMAP so that it can be related to CLUSTERMAP. This should work. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: This does help me. Many thanks for the response and effort. However,it seems i will have to ask the DBA to provide me access to declare procedures which currently i do not have. This method has provided me the required direction to complete the task. Many thanks. :)

Comment: If you don't have permissions to write and execute procedures, you can run this query directly as well, depends upon your exact requirement though. Anyway you wish. Cheers!! :)

Comment: Yes, but the query above will run through an automated Unix system that reads queries from an excel file and run them in informatica workflows. (Informatica to run multiple sessions in parallel). I believe i cannot run  Such an SQL in Informatica.